# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by %s

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I keep getting this error saying "ERROR Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by %s. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: [https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks"](https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks%22).
I have tried different solutions but I can't find where the problem is. I also installed eslint to try to find some bugs with the hooks but I can't find any.

```
const HandleScreen = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

    const isLogin = useAppSelector((state) => state.login.isLogin);
    const alreadyLogIn =
      useAppSelector((state) => state.login.userName) &&
      useAppSelector((state) => state.login.password);

    useEffect(() => {
      async function retriveData() {
        await createTable();
        await getDataFromDB(dispatch);

        setLoading(false);
      }
      retriveData()
    }, []);

    if(loading) {return}
    else return (isLogin || alreadyLogIn !== '') ?  <MainScreen /> : <LoginScreen />;
  };
```

And this is my error message

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by %s. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render

%s, HandleScreen, 
1. useState                   useState
2. useContext                 useContext
3. useContext                 useContext
4. useRef                     useRef
5. useMemo                    useMemo
6. useSyncExternalStore       useSyncExternalStore
7. useEffect                  useEffect
8. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
9. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
10. useContext                useContext
11. useRef                    useRef
12. useMemo                   useMemo
13. useSyncExternalStore      useSyncExternalStore
14. useEffect                 useEffect
15. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
16. useDebugValue             useDebugValue
17. useEffect                 useContext
, 
    in HandleScreen (created by App)
    ...
```

Comment: Remember: the error is "just more text", so please copy and paste it into your post as text (with appropriate formatting). [Don't put images of text in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Also remember to reduce your code to [mcve] form because it looks like code you're not showing is involved here, too, and the code you do show can almost certainly have lots of parts removed while still producing this error, just with fewer hooks involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see the issue can be inside the `useAppSelector` hook use for `alreadyLogIn`

Try this:

```
const alreadyLogIn = useAppSelector((state) => {
    return state.login.userName && state.login.password;
});
```

Comment: That solved the problem, do you know why at a conceptual level the code I was trying to implement is wrong?

Comment: @JulianFranco it could be occurring after the user logs out, and their `userName` is set to null. This will prevent the second `useAppSelector((state) => state.login.password);` from running because the previous condition will be falsey. React will detect this and complain

Comment: As far as I know the Selector hook gives access to the state and you can either directly return the state you want or modify the return value (such as using filters and sorting on maps as such). 

The hook when called directly might be returning something else causing the issue